# SQL transaction history-Delete

Tags: sql-server, sql-delete

Somehow one of the tables in our database got all its records erased. Is there a way for me to find out from TL or any kind of logs to find out what command was run on SQL. Either a delete or Truncate.

The TL grew to about 500GB seems like the day records got deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use undocumented `fn_dblog()` function or thirdparty third party tools, like [ApexSQL Log](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_log.aspx) - Trial can be enough for your purpose. It is a bit tricky to get command via `fn_dblog()` but there are many examples how to deal with this function: [0](https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/read-a-sql-server-transaction-log/), [1](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2018/05/17/sql-server-reading-transaction-log-to-identified-who-dropped-a-table/), [2](http://rusanu.com/2014/03/10/how-to-read-and-interpret-the-sql-server-log/). There is also `fn_dump_dblog()` to read separate log files.

Comment: Thank you so very much. I have a back up copy of that database and currently I am trying to restore it on my local machine, it says 100% done but its still spinning, I guess because the TL size is so huge and I cant shrink it because I need that information.   I have installed ApexSQL Log but it looks like I cant use it until restore is complete. I wonder if there is another way to use just the .ldf file and check TL without actually restoring the db.